# ¿Por qué al abrir el documento PDF creado en C# me dice que el documento PDF está dañado?

Tags: c#, pdf, formato, descarga

Intenté con la extensión docs y me abre correctamente el documento en formato word, en este caso se requiere crear un PDF para que no se pueda modificar sin embargo al abrir la descarga comenta que está dañado.

```
public void CloseWord()
{
    
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document doc = _objWordApplication.Documents[@"\\192.168.4.9\estadistica\suc\Apps\Procest\Procest\"+sarco] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document;
    Documento = sruta + ".PDF";
    doc.SaveAs(Documento, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    doc.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);***texto en negrita***
    
    try

    {
```

Answer (score 0):

Con eso estas creando un documento de Word y solo le estas cambiando la extensión a PDF.

Prueba a usar alguna librería como por ejemplo:

https://sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-focus/